# Node.js doesn't load after reboot using upstart on debian squeeze

Tags: debian, upstart

I have been dabbling with Node.js lately, and I came across this article on how to get it to start automatically after a reboot:

http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit

In particular, the article recommends that I use upstart (I'm running Debian Squeeze).  I've been able to install upstart fine, and when I use the "start" and "stop" commands, everything works perfect.  However, whenever I reboot, Node.js never runs.  The log is empty and I can't figure out why it's not working.  I'm ready to give up on upstart, but I want to know if anyone else is having the same issue?

Here is my upstart script:

```
description "node.js server"
author      "me"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0) 
# i also tried "start on startup", still does not work.
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 5 60

script
exec sudo -u node sh -c "/usr/local/bin/node /opt/apps/firstapp/app.js >> /var/log/firstapp.log 2>&1"
end script
```

Comment: Hmm. I was not aware that squeeze uses Upstart?! Can you confirm that Upstart is really used after your install? Have you configured `sudo` to execute `sh` without prompting for a password/passphrase?

Comment: Yes, apparently you can install upstart on squeeze (you do get a warning though), but since I'm new to upstart, most of the guides I've read have said to confirm that it is working, you merely have to type the commands "start <programname>" and "stop <programname>" to confirm it's working--both of which worked on my end.  And yes, I have configured sudo to execute sh without prompting for a password.

Comment: So what is in the (existing?) firstapp.log?

Comment: the firstapp.log file is blank.  And yes, the user "node" has full permissions to write to the file.

Comment: change the 2nd last line to `exec echo "Executed" >> /var/log/firstapp.log 2>&1`. Does it get filled then?

Comment: It does not get filled in when I reboot, but it does get filled in when I run `sudo start firstapp`

Comment: So then you Upstart is not installed correctly or the script doesn't get triggered.

Comment: I installed upstart via `apt-get install upstart` on debian.  My guess is that upstart is still too new/unstable for debian (as of this writing, 8/17/2011) and I might just scrap it and go back to sysvinit for now, until it becomes more mature for debian in the next few years.  Thanks for all your help though!

Answer (score 1):

try to use filesystem instead of local-filesystems. Possibly /usr/local is NOT ready mounted on local-filesystems. (I had a similar issue once)